# Solidity – Safe Remote Purchase

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, smart-contract-wallets

For a group project at the university, I'm looking for help by extending a current smart contract "Safe Remote Purchase".

The contract will look like that:

**1.** Seller deposits 1 (originally 2, but in my opinion a seller takes a risk of sending         the item without receiving any funds), item put on sale for 1, contract balance is now 1.

**2.** Buyer offers to buy, pays in 2, half of which is the sale price and half of which is   a deposit. Contract balance is now 3.

**3.** Seller ships item.

**4.** Buyer confirms receipt, gets their deposit of 1 back. That leaves a contract balance of 2, which is sent to the seller: 1 for the seller's deposit, 1 for the sale price.

Now I want to include the following two functions and need help by that:

**1st function – Time Function:**

- After the seller deposited his funds, there should be a time function, that the buyer will have 2 days to deposit his funds.

-> Buyer deposits his funds and Seller ships the item.

Buyer has now 1 year to confirm the receipt of the item. If he won't confirm it within 1 year, funds which were deposited, should be sent to a dead address.

**2nd function:** Is there a function to send the funds automatically to a dead address after one year if Buyer did not confirm?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here the code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.11;

contract PurchaseAgreement {
uint public value;
address payable public seller;
address payable public buyer;

enum State { Created, Locked, Release, Inactive }
State public state;

constructor() payable {
    seller = payable(msg.sender);
    value = msg.value / 2;
}

/// The function cannot be called at the current state.
error InvalidState();
///  Ony the buyer can call this function
error OnlyBuyer();
///  Ony the seller can call this function
error OnlySeller();

modifier inState(State state_) {
    if (state != state_) {
        revert InvalidState();
    }
    _;
}

modifier onlyBuyer() {
    if (msg.sender != buyer) {
        revert OnlyBuyer();
    }
    _;
}

modifier onlySeller() {
    if (msg.sender != seller) {
        revert OnlySeller();
    }
    _;
}

function confirmPurchase() external inState(State.Created) payable {
    require(msg.value == (2 * value), "Please send in 2x the purchase amount");
    buyer = payable(msg.sender);
    state = State.Locked;
}

function confirmReceived() external onlyBuyer inState(State.Locked) {
    state = State.Release;
    buyer.transfer(value);
}

function paySeller() external onlySeller inState(State.Release) {
  state = State.Inactive;
  seller.transfer(3 * value);
}

function abort() external onlySeller inState(State.Created) {
    state = State.Inactive;
    seller.transfer(address(this).balance);
}


}
```